# How to save arabic words into oracle database?

Tags: java, encoding, character, arabic

I want to save the arabic word into oracle database. User type a arabic word from client side and submit that word.In client side I printed that word by using alert it is shown arabic text. But the word shown in server side, java console (by using Sytem.out.println) as  `Ø´Ø§Ø­ÙØ©`. So it is shown in db as `????`. I saw the related post, in one of the post discuss changing the 'text file encoding' into UTF-8 in Eclipse, I changed the 'text file encoding' into UTF-8. But no effect it is showing previous characters like `Ø´Ø§Ø­ÙØ©`. Then I changed the applications 'text file encoding' into UTF-8 , then got same output. I think the word sending into db like this that is why db shows as `????`. Is any solution?

my code is in Java

```
vehicleServiceModel.setVehicleType(request.getParameter("vehicleType"));

    System.out.println("vehicle Type :  "+vehicleServiceModel.getVehicleType());
```

client side

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache : false,
        url: "addvehicle.htm",
        data:{vehName:VehicleName,make:Make,model:Model,color:Color,plateNumber:PlateNumber,driverName:DriverName,vehicleType:VehicleType,vehTimeZone:vehTimeZone},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: Success,
        error: Error
    });

    function Success(data, status) {
     //some code
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Command line, you need to set the code page to [1256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195058.aspx) (Arabic). But storing arabic texts in a database, you need to set the column data to UTF-8. Also, make sure that your charset is set to UTF-8 (if you're doing a web page).

Comment: would you please explain your answer

Comment: where to set 1256? I already set the all jsp page utf-8 and set the text file encoding in eclipse as utf-8 but no effect

Comment: Are you displaying your output on Eclipse console?

Comment: actually i need to save, but can I see the word which is send to save into db by using console

Comment: Then you're confusing your question. Where is your code failing? Is it on the display side, storing side, or what?

Comment: actually i don't know where it is failing, I saw in db as ????? and in console as Ø´Ø§Ø­ÙØ©.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this question myself.Hopefully this will help some other.

My issue resolved by :

I changed

in java:

```
vehicleServiceModel.setVehicleType(request.getParameter("vehicleType"));
String str = vehicleServiceModel.getVehicleType();
    str = new String(str.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("vehicle Type :  "+str);
    vehicleServiceModel.setVehicleType(str);
```

Now it is resolved and arabic words saved into the database.

For more details Please have a look into  [this](http://ahmadhashem.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/handle-arabic-encoding-common-issues-in-java-web-development/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use UTF-8 all the way, i.e. in the web page, in Eclipse and your source code, and in the database (NLS_CHARACTERSET or define the column as NVARCHAR2). This way you will not need conversions.